# Amazon DynamoDBv2 QueryOperationConfig SelectValues.Count not working

Tags: .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I have this piece of code like this:

```
var options = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
                {
                    ConditionalOperator = ConditionalOperatorValues.Or,
                    OverrideTableName = nameTable,
                    ConsistentRead = true
                };

new QueryOperationConfig()
                    {
                        IndexName = indexName,
                        Filter = queryFilter,
                        Select = SelectValues.Count
                    };

result = context.FromQueryAsync<TEntity>(queryConfig, options).GetRemainingAsync().Result;
```

as per the documentation, it should return just the count of values that match the filter, at least, the piece of code in the SelectValues class says that

```
//
    // Summary:
    //     An enumeration of all supported Select values for Query and Scan. Value of Count
    //     will force service to return the number of items, not the items themselves.
```

but result is always an empty list; how can i make the count work ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are still looking for the answer, this is the solution:

```
new QueryOperationConfig()
                    {
                        IndexName = indexName,
                        Filter = queryFilter,
                        Select = SelectValues.Count,
                        ConsistentRead = true
                    };
var table = context.GetTargetTable<TEntity>();
var search = table.Query(queryConfig);
result = search.Count;
```

Having ConsistentRead set to true will cause it to give you real time updates when the table is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working on Document level...
You can try to do this in low level model.

```
        int count = 0;
        Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> lastKey = null;


        do
        {
            var request = new QueryRequest
            {
                TableName = "tableNmae",
                IndexName = "indexName",
                KeyConditionExpression = "ID= :v_ID",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
                {
                    {
                        ":v_ID",
                        new AttributeValue
                        {
                            N = "1"
                        }
                    }
                },

                ConsistentRead = false,
                Select = Select.COUNT,
                ExclusiveStartKey = lastKey
            };

            var respone = await tableClient.QueryAsync(request);
            count += respone.Count;
            lastKey = respone.LastEvaluatedKey;

        } while (lastKey != null && lastKey.Count != 0);
```